# Convert multidimensional array to one-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a multidimensional array. I want to group the values in this and know how many.

I've created a new array. I've looped a multidimensional array. If the current value does not exist in the new array, I add this value into the array. But I couldn't do it dynamically, they were all added to the bottom. I couldn't add it to "subCategories".

In this way I have a multidimensional array.

```
   currentArray = [
     [1, 2, 3, 5],
     [1, 2, 3, 4],
     [1, 2, 3, 4],
     [1, 2, 3, 4],
     [1, 2, 3, 4],
     [1, 2, 3, 4],
     [1, 2, 3, 4]
   ]
```

I used a loop like this.

```
    newArray= [];
    for (let i = 0; i < currentArray.length; i++) {
          for (let k = 0; k < currentArray[i].length; k++) {
            let obj = { id: currentArray[i][k], subCategories: [] };
            let index = newCategories.findIndex(x => x.id === obj.id);
            if (index === -1) {
              if (k === 0) {
                newCategories.push(obj);
              }
            } else {
              newCategories[index].subCategories.push(obj);
            }
          }
        }
```

I used a loop like this but I did not get a successful result. Logic error in the current code and I couldn't figure it out.

> I want the same elements in the array to be added to the new array only once. And I want to get "count" in the last elements.

So the output I want to achieve is as follows.

```
   {
     "id": 1,
     "subCategories": [
       {
         "id": 2,
         "subCategories": [
           {
             "id": 3,
             "subCategories": [
               {
                 "id": 5,
                 "count": 1,
                 "subCategories": []
               },
               {
                 "id": 4,
                 "count": 6,
                 "subCategories": []
               }
             ]
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
```

Comment: So if you "didn't want to add the codes because it was so complicated" how do you expect us to add it if it's so complicated?

Comment: The explanation of what you are trying to do and achieve is not clear to me

Comment: What happens when `currentArray = [
     [1, 2, 3, 5],
     [5, 3, 1, 2],
     [3, 1, 3, 1],
   ]`

Comment: Sorry. I've added my problem and the solution I've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce the array by reduceing the inner array and look for the wanted id.

```js
var array = [[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]],
    result = array
        .reduce((r, a) => {
            var o = a.reduce((p, id) => {
                var temp = p.subCategories.find(q => q.id === id);
                if (!temp) {
                    p.subCategories.push(temp = { id, subCategories: [] });
                }
                return temp;
            }, r);
            o.count = (o.count || 0) + 1;
            return r;
        }, { subCategories: [] })
        .subCategories;

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This is in the same style as you had, by using a starting object which matches the inner format and a search for the items for returning this object for next level.

```js
var currentArray = [[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]],
    newArray = [],
    temp,
    item;

for (let i = 0; i < currentArray.length; i++) {
    temp = { subCategories: newArray };
    for (let k = 0; k < currentArray[i].length; k++) {
        item = temp.subCategories.find(x => x.id === currentArray[i][k]);
        if (!item) {
            temp.subCategories.push(item = { id: currentArray[i][k], subCategories: [] });
        }
        temp = item;
    }
    temp.count = (item.count || 0) + 1;
}

console.log(newArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know "reduce". That's exactly what I wanted. Even if I couldn't explain my problem, I would like to thank you for understanding and solving.