# Javascript reduce to Php array_reduce

Tags: javascript, php

I have a 'Javascript reduce' code, where we print elements with the same value once.

```js
var array = [[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]];
        result = array
            .reduce((r, a) => {
                var o = a.reduce((p, id) => {
                    var temp = p.subCategories.find(q => q.id === id);
                    if (!temp) {
                        p.subCategories.push(temp = { id, subCategories: [] });
                    }
                    return temp;
                }, r);
                o.count = (o.count || 0) + 1;
                return r;
            }, { subCategories: [] })
            .subCategories;
    console.log(result);
```

I want to convert this to php. I tried the code below.

```
$categories = [
         [1, 2, 3, 5],
         [1, 2, 3, 4],
         [1, 2, 3, 4],
         [1, 2, 3, 4],
         [1, 2, 3, 4],
         [1, 2, 3, 4],
         [1, 2, 3, 4]
       ]

$result = array_reduce($categories, function ($r, $a) {
             $o = array_reduce($a, function ($p, $id) {
                 if (isset($p['subCategories']))
                    $temp = array_search($id, array_column($p['subCategories'], 'id'));
                 else
                    $temp = false;
                 if (!$temp) {
                     $obj = (object)array(
                         'id' => 0,
                         'subCategories' => array()
                     );
                     $p['subCategories'] = array();
                     array_push($p['subCategories'], $obj);
                 } else {
                     $temp = $p['subCategories'][$temp];
                 }
                 return $temp;
             }, $r);
             $o->count = 0;
             $o->count = $o->count + 1;
             return $r;
        });
        return $result;
```

I've had problems here in the count section and it didn't work properly. Where could I fault?

Comment: Do you want a PHP equivalent for JS Reduce?

Comment: funny, i have seen this code [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54531363/1447675) ...

Comment: Yes I want to get the Php state of the Javascript code running above

Comment: @NinaScholz - interesting. What is this?

Comment: I think that you're misunderstanding what does array_reduce does in PHP : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-reduce.php

Comment: maybe you the the other [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54531363/1447675) with just PHP flavour from mey.

Comment: I'm just trying second solution. Will definitely work. Thank you very much for your help.